# Removing all characters from python list except some capital letter

Tags: python

I have a list in python which contains a lot of different characters, for example space, |, >, numbers, and small letters, but I only want to keep some capital letter (A,B,C,D). If I try this, it doesen't work, I almost get the desired list, but not only A,B,C,D remain.

```
with open("text.mfa") as f:
     content = f.read()
mylist = list(content)

letters = ['A','B','C','D']
i = 0
while i < (len(mylist)-1)
     if mylist[i] != letters[0] or letters[1] or letters[2] or letters[3]
            mylist.remove(mylist[i])
     i+=1
```

Comment: Your comparison with `or` is buggy. Replicate the first test after each `or`

Comment: Also, **use a for loop**, and don't modify a list while you iterate over it.

Comment: You can also `import string` and then use `if mylist[i] not in set(string.ascii_uppercase):` But you're modifying a list during iteration which is going to cause issues e.g. I assume you'll hit `IndexError` with this code. Just build a different list containing only the characters you _do_ want.

Comment: `i+=1` should probably be in an `else` if you go down this road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using filter.

```
myfilteredlist = list(filter(lambda s: s in letters, mylist))
```

Comment: Only this filtering way solve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A more Pythonic way would probably be to use a list comprehension and the `in` operator:

```
mylist = [x for x in content if x in letters]
```

Comment: I **think** you might have to remove that `not`. It's my understanding that OP wants to keep all characters that appear within letters, and exclude those that do not, while you're doing the exact oposite.

Comment: @JavoSN. Thanks for the catch. I misread the question. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at your if statement:

```
if mylist[i] != letters[0] or letters[1] or letters[2] or letters[3]
```

If put in brackets python processes this as:

```
if (mylist[i] != letters[0]) or (letters[1]) or (letters[2]) or (letters[3]):
```

Every character evaluates to True, to this means that because letters[1] etc. evaluate to true you always evaluate your whole expression to True.

Comment: I feel like there is something missing here. Otherwise you just have a comment (that @MosesKoledoye already made)

Comment: Jep, sorry :s accidentally pressed the submit button why trying to add a code sample...

Comment: Retracted. Happens to me all the time too, especially on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Use `in` instead of `or` (this check if the element is in the list).

```
if not mylist[i] in letters:
    mylist.remove(mylist[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop instead of a while loop since for loop iterates over a set number of values. To check if the word is in letters you can do this:

```
with open("text.mfa") as f:
     mylist = list(f.read())
mynewlist = []
letters = ['A','B','C','D']
for word in mylist:
      if word not in letters: #if word is not in letters
            mynewlist.append(word) #adds the word to a new list
```

Comment: It's always a bad idea to remove things from a list whilst iterating over it.

Comment: You're right I didn't even realize. Just answered accordingly

Comment: Also, this is not quite Python. The keywords should not be capitalized.

Comment: @MadPhysicist sorry I'm on my phone, it automatically capitalizes everything :p